# Ubuntu 16.10 DRM AMDGPU CIK support?

Tags: amd-graphics, 16.10

Is CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU_CIK set to "Y" in the mainline kernel?

I have an AMD r9 390. Set amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1 in kernel boot parameters and blacklisted radeon drivers and it still will not switch me to AMDGPU drivers.

Thanks to anyone who helps in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about the "mainline" (ie upstream) kernel without any Ubuntu patches/changes, or the default Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: default 16.10 kernel

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is set by looking at the appropriate config file for your current kernel, in the `/boot/` directory:

```
grep CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU_CIK /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Thanks, checked it. Nope, not set. I don't understand why they did that.